# Entry FindByName getting always null in xamarin forms mvvm

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a button 
and i want to focus an entry on button click
so my button command is:

```
public Command FocusPassword
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() =>
                {
                    Entry myEntry= Application.Current.MainPage.FindByName<Entry>("pEntry");
                    passwordEntry.Focus();
                });
            }
        }
```

myEntry always returning null,so how to solve this?

Comment: Did you provide this name to the entry? Using x:Name?

Comment: yes I Provide this.

Answer (score 2):

I simply solve this:

```
Page currentPage = Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
                    Entry passwordEntry = currentPage.FindByName<Entry>("PassEntry");
                    passwordEntry.Focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it `myEntry` that is null, or `passwordEntry`? You are assigning the returned object to `myEntry` but then trying to set the focus on `passwordEntry`:

```
Entry myEntry= Application.Current.MainPage.FindByName<Entry>("pEntry");
passwordEntry.Focus();
```

And yes, make sure that the `Entry` does have the `x:Name` set to `pEntry`, e.g.:

```
 <Entry x:Name="pEntry" ... />
```

Comment: I used it but it always getting null

Comment: Are you sure the entry is in your current mainpage?

Comment: Yes this entry is in my mainpage

Comment: Okay, what is the name of this page? and I mean the name of the axml

Comment: my page name is LoginPage.xaml

Comment: I simply solve this
Page currentPage = Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
                    Entry myEntry = currentPage.FindByName<Entry>("pEntry");
                    myEntry.Focus();

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use my demo as well.
[image]

`MainPage.xaml` (Do not forget to BindingContext)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EntryDemo"
         x:Class="EntryDemo.MainPage">

<StackLayout>

    <Grid Margin="10">
     <Grid.BindingContext>
            <local:BindingViewModel/>
     </Grid.BindingContext>

     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Entry 
        Grid.Row="0"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        Text="account"
        x:Name="accountEntry"
         />
    <Entry 
        Text="password"
        Grid.Row="1"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        x:Name="pEntry"
     />
    <Button
        Grid.Row="2"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        x:Name="MyButton"
        Text="FocusEntry "
        Command="{Binding FocusCommand}"
        />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

You should run `FindByName` in execute method 
`BindingViewModel.cs`

```
 public class BindingViewModel: BindableObject
{
    public BindingViewModel()
    {

        FocusCommand = new Command(
            execute: () =>
            {
                Entry accountEntry = Application.Current.MainPage.FindByName<Entry>("accountEntry");
                Entry myEntry = Application.Current.MainPage.FindByName<Entry>("pEntry");
                accountEntry.Focus();

            }
     );

    }
    public ICommand FocusCommand { private set; get; }
}
```